# How to exclude Username field from AWS Amplify React UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

I have a simple component using [@aws-amplify/ui-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/ui-react). I want to be able render a sign up form consisting of "email", "password" and "confirm password".

My component for rendering the AWS amplify sign up form looks like this:

```
function Auth(){

  const formFields = {
    signUp: {
      email: {
        order:1
      },
      password: {
        order: 5
      },
      confirm_password: {
        order: 6
      }
    },
   }

   return <Authenticator formFields={formFields} />
}
```

For some reason, even though I have explicitly stated what fields I want rendered, it still includes the username field:

[image]

How can I omit the "username" field from the sign up form?

As far as I can tell, the `<Authenticator />` component doesn't have an exclude field and I would have thought the `formFields` prop would be for what fields to include so should automatically exclude fields I haven't included.

Could it be something to do with my Cognito config?

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "pool" {
  name = "order-ease-dev"
  username_attributes = ["email"]
  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]

  account_recovery_setting {
    recovery_mechanism {
      name     = "verified_email"
      priority = 1
    }

    recovery_mechanism {
      name     = "verified_phone_number"
      priority = 2
    }
  }
}

 resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "order-ease-dashboard-client-dev"
  user_pool_id = "${aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id}"
  explicit_auth_flows = ["ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH", "ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH", "ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH"]
 }
```

I want my sign up to only include "email", "password" and "confirm password". How can I acheive this using the `@aws-amplify/ui-react` ui library?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change `auth` from `aws-amplify`. Changing `@aws-amplify/ui-react` alone doesn't work.

For more info:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-up